# Decode & from &amp; from XML with ToString()

Tags: c#, xml

How do I get the code below to return the desired output.  This is just plain csharp in a main, no ASP.NET.

```
//Desired output: <amp>Before & After</amp>

//instead of

//Current output: <amp>Before &amp; After</amp>

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string amp = "Before & After";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(sb);
        XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("amp");
        xmlWriter.WriteString(amp);
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

        global::System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
    }
```

---

Here is how I solved the particular problem.

```
        string amp = "Before & After";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(sb);
        XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("amp");
        xmlWriter.WriteString(amp);
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

        StringReader valueStringReader = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
        XmlTextReader valueXmlReader = new XmlTextReader(valueStringReader);

        valueXmlReader.MoveToContent();

        global::System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(valueXmlReader.ReadString());
```

Comment: I don't think the desired output is valid XML so I doubt the XmlTextWriter will do it for you.

Comment: HtmlTextWriter might though...

Comment: Correct, the desired output is NOT xml.  I want it converted back to readable characters in the string buffer..

Comment: Do not use `new XmlTextWriter()`. It's been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Here is how I solved the particular problem.

```
        string amp = "Before & After";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(sb);
        XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("amp");
        xmlWriter.WriteString(amp);
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

        StringReader valueStringReader = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
        XmlTextReader valueXmlReader = new XmlTextReader(valueStringReader);

        valueXmlReader.MoveToContent();

        global::System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(valueXmlReader.ReadString());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want invalid XML create it yourself.

```
        string amp = "Before & After";

        // don't really do this, it's very wrong
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<amp>");
        sb.Append(amp);
        sb.Append("</amp>");

        Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

But this is **NOT** valid xml, so don't do it.  If you want to use XML, you need to use valid XML.  Your original code sample is correct.

If you want something that is more human readable, then don't use XML, use YAML.

http://www.yaml.org/

```
amp: Before & After
```

Comment: The above was just a repro of a larger problem.  I don't want to create invalid XML, I just want to write the XML in a readable output.

Answer (score 1):

The desired output is not valid XML. The current output is identical to a CDATA section in that `Before &amp; After` and `<![CDATA[Before & After]]>` are simply two different ways of escaping an ampersand so that you can have valid XML. In either case, if you use any XML parser to read the content of the `<amp>` tag, it will return `Before & After`.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your text into a CDataSection - see [XmlDocument.CreateCDataSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createcdatasection.aspx).